# Returning values from a Class Method

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns

I think this is a silly question - but I am not being able to fully grasp it :(

Suppose I have a class called `Categories` which has a function called `getCategories()`

```
class Categories
{

  function __construct()
  {

  }

  function getCategories()
  {
    //sql to get all categories from db 
    return $categories;
  }
}
```

And in other classes I will do something like:

```
$cats = new Categories();
$cats->getCategories();
```

Now my question is, there are many places where I need to use the categories. So what if I created a variable called `$cats` as a member of `categories` class and loaded it in the constructor and just passed it back when anyone called `getCategories()` :

```
class Categories
{
  var $cats; 

  function __construct()
  {
     $this->cats = $this->getCategories(); 
  }

  function getCategories()
  {
    //return loaded class variable instead of running db query again
    return $this->cats;
  }
}
```

This way I do not need to hit database every time anyone requests categories. Is this approach good? bad? Should I do this or stick with db query each time?

Comment: This question is a better fit for [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). But in short: no, it's not a good idea. `var $cats` is a PHP4-style property, PHP5 uses access modifiers (`public $cats;` or `protected $cats;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This way I do not need to hit database every time anyone requests categories. Is this approach good? bad? Should I do this or stick with db query each time?

This all really depends on the nature of your categories property. For example, could they change after you have pulled them down? If so then caching when you initially create the class and never hitting the database again could potentially mean working with stale data which may or may not be an issue for you.

On the other hand, if they are fairly static and very rarely change then caching them on first access might be a better alternative e.g.

```
function getCategories()
{
    if (!isset($this->cats)) {
        $this->cats = // load from DB
    }
    return $this->cats;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that answer - shouldn't it be `if (!isset($this->cats)) {`

Comment: @open_sourse oops, yep should be.

Answer (score 0):

There is all good, but `var` is deprecated, you should use `public`, `private` or `protected` instead.